# iPhone SDK - Using touches to delete images

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, image, touches

how can you delete an image by using touches in the iphone sdk? Im making a game with images so i was wondering if there is a way were if you touch an image it gets deleted from the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can add **UITapGestureRecognizer** to your image view, and in the recognizer action you can get the image view by using `recognizer.view` propery. And you can delete/remove it from its super view by using `[image removeFromSuperview]` method.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tgr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onImageTapped:)];
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:tgr];
[tgr release];
```

And the *onImageTapped:* method looks like this,

```
- (void)onImageTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {

    UIImageView *imgView = (UIImageView*) recognizer.view;
    [imgView removeFromSuperview];
}
```